# Write a program to convert farenheit to celcius using a function

Tags: python, function

I am new to python coding
I need to write a program that will convert Farenheit to celcius using a function. I have some of the code but I am getting an error. Please Help

```
#define a function
def Convert (F):
    Celcius=(F-32)*5/9
    Print Celcius
#get input
F=int(input("Enter a temperature in Farenheit "))
#call function
Convert (F)
```

this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXX", line 13, in <module>
    Convert(F)
  File "XXXXX", line 6, in Convert
    Print(Celcius)
NameError: name 'Print' is not defined
```

Comment: *What* error you're getting? Please provide a [mcve] so we can better help you.

Comment: `print` without uppercase

Comment: Try `print(Celcius)` instead of `Print Celcius`.

Answer (score 2):

Use print with (), use print instead of Print

```
#define a function
def Convert (F):
    Celcius=(F-32)*5/9
    print(Celcius)
#get input
F=int(input("Enter a temperature in Farenheit "))
#call function
Convert (F)
```

Comment: yes, use print instead of Print!

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `print` with a capital P, also it's best practice to `return` in a function like this than print in it.

```
def celcius(f):
    return (f-32)*5/9

f=int(input("Enter a temperature in Farenheit "))
print celcius(f)
```

Also, I made your `CamelCase` more pythonic. It's best to keep with the languages standardizations especially if you're new.

Answer (score 1):

Source this [jsFiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/fahrenheit-to-celsius/)

```
print("Python 3.4 Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion program."'\n')

def Celsius():
  fahrenheit = float(input("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit."'\n'))
  print("You entered %s degrees."'\n' % fahrenheit)
  celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
  print("The temperature is %d celsius")% celsius

Celsius()
```

Answer (score 1):

it was print with a lowercase. thanks julien and everyone else. cant believe i didnt catch that

Answer (score 1):

```
def Conversion(n): 
    return(n - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0
n = 40
x = Conversion(n) 
print (x)
```

Here make sure you write small p, you've put Capital (P).

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this:

```
f = input("Enter Temperature in Fahrenheit: ");

fah = float(f);

cel = (fah-32)/1.8;

print("Temperature in Celsius =",cel);
```